# How to read data in json file in javascript to use it for google charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, flask

I have data in a path static/data.json.I am trying to plot chart using google charts.I want to take out data in data.json file and use it for google charts.

> data.json is given below

```js
data = '[{"k": "RAM" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Camera" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Design" , "v":0.05},{"k": "Processor" , "v":0},]';
```

my html code is in template/isworked.html.

> Below code is isworked.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/json" src="static/d.json"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      
    
  
 var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

 function drawChart() {
 
        // Create the data table.
        
        
        //loading data from json
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Feature');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Positive');
      var f,n;
        for(var i = 0 ; i<data.length;i++){
         f = data[i].k
         n = data[i].v
         data.addRows([[f,n]])
        }
        
        // Set chart options
        var options = {'title':'Pie Chart',
                       'width':800,
                       'height':700};

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
       
      }
    </script>
  </head>
```

I am not able to plot graph.
This data.json is generated from a python script. I am running everyting using **flask** framework in **Ubuntu**

I have no experience in this topic. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I am getting error like  : Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Answer (score 1):

UberKaeL is correct.

**update:**
corrected multiple problems with the code and data, e.g., the trailing comma in the data. It works now ... click the "Run Code Snippet" button.

"mydata" is the problem.  You are attempting to use data before the json file has loaded. That triggers the error. And mydata is not used for anything. You also need to add a DIV to hold the pie chart. The code snippet below works, but the json data is incorrect for drawing a pie chart. Correct the data and it should work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var mydata = [{"k": "RAM" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Camera" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Design" , "v":0.05},{"k": "Processor" , "v": 0}];
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 
  function drawChart() {
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         data.addColumn('string', 'Feature');
         data.addColumn('number', 'Positive');
       var f,n;
         for(var i = 0 ; i<mydata.length;i++){
          f = mydata[i].k
          n = mydata[i].v
          data.addRows([[f,n]])
         }
         var options = {'title':'Pie Chart', 'width':800, 'height':700};
         var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
         chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: If I give json data inside the program it works, If the data is in external json file it is not working.

Comment: thk u...but for external json file its not working still

Comment: How to use properly the if the json data is in other file, for ex : my json data file is in :static/d.json file

Comment: Your json data is incorrect. It will not work until you fix your data file.

Comment: OK...If the data given like your code it works for me,,,,same data kept in file ,not able to load,...why??..how to corrrect my json data?

Comment: thank uvery much. I need with external json file , can you plz tell me how to load it?

Comment: Your json data contains an extra comma at the end.  This causes an error in the loop where you create your table.  ..."v":0},]'; should be ..."v":0}]';

Comment: ok...i removed , I worked...but for external json file I need...can u plz tell me tat..hw to do

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="static/data.json"></script> and the data.json file content is: var mydata = [{"k": "RAM" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Camera" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Design" , "v":0.05},{"k": "Processor" , "v":0}];

Comment: ya..if i rewrite it like that now error is   :  Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(anonymous function) @ is_done:22
is_done:32 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Robert ..its working if I run it in localhost......but I am using FLASK...there it is not nowrking

Answer (score 1):

After a while it seems like your page runs the code before loading the json file. Reading json like that is not a good practice, is better to do an AJAX request like [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

so if your are using jQuery do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSON</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var mydata=jQuery.getJSON("static/d.json");
            if(mydata) {
                alert("yay worked");
            }
            else {
                alert("something is wrong");
            }
            //rest of your code
            //function drawChart() { ...

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also is a good practice to enclose your program inside a `$(document).ready` and remember to remove last comma in your JSON:

```
data = '[{"k": "RAM" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Camera" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Design" , "v":0.05},{"k": "Processor" , "v":0}]';
```

@Robert gives you a good answer about how to draw the chart

Comment: If I give json data inside the program it works, If the data is in external json file it is not working.

Comment: thk u , alert showing : yaw worked,,,but no data in pie chart...like balnk

Comment: the data is now in mydata, you need to rewrite your program as other @Robert told

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `mydata` where you put json read values.

data contains an empty `new google.visualization.DataTable()` and the loop are reading values from it, not from `mydata`.

Comment: I get error in line : var mydata = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: where should I change now?

Comment: make sure `<script type="application/json" src="static/data.json"></script>` is load checking `if(data) {alert("yes")}` or using `onload`/`ready` (jQuery) method. Probably your program starts before it load the data.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined(anonymous function) @ is_done:21

Comment: so is not loaded, try to check file directory and wait until everything is loaded, remeber `$(document).ready(function(){ your_program });`

Comment: is this correct way to use : var mydata = JSON.parse(data);  ?

Comment: how to use above statement in program?

Comment: when I used JSON.parse on your data it shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]` try to remove last comma "," before "]"

Comment: I am getting : Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined.... ...Shall I give you the Flask code also??

Comment: If I give json data inside the program it works, If the data is in external json file it is not working.   like :           data = '[{"k": "RAM" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Camera" , "v":0.515625},{"k": "Design" , "v":0.05},{"k": "Processor" , "v":0}]';